# Changing a navigation text with .replaceWith and keep it persistent

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, replacewith

I have an event on my site that if you click on a button the navigation text changes and I would like for it to persist throughout the site. Right now it works but once I move to a new page it changes back to the original state.

```
    $('.create-regulatory-release').click(function(){
    $('.setup p').replaceWith('<p>Regulatory Filing</p>');

});
```

Comment: Set a cookie when you change it and check for that on `document.ready` of every page.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is written in javascript, and javascript runs on the client computer -- not on the server. If you want something to persist after the page is reloaded or changed, you either need to store those values on the client side (with javascript cookies) or on the server.

I would look into jstorage if you want something easy:
http://www.jstorage.info/